# What is the proper method for Shnayim Mikrah V'Echad Targum?

Tags: halacha, shnayim-mikra

What is the preferred method to accomplish the mitzvah of *Shnayim Mikra V'Echad Targum* - (reading the weekly parsha by reading the Torah verses twice and *Targum Onkelos* once)?

- Should each verse be read twice then the Targum, and repeat the process for the next verse until the parsha is complete?    or...
- Should all the verses for the whole parsha be read in the Torah text, do this again, then read all the Targum explanations for the whole parsha once?    or...
- Something else?

If only one method is the correct way, *bedi'eved* (post facto), if a person read it using the other method, would he fulfill the mitzvah?

Answer (score 5):

**Summary**

There are a lot of opinions. Here are some of them:

According to the **Kitzur Shulchan Aruch** in 72:13 - [סימן עב - גדל קדשת שבת והמחללו הרי הוא כמו עובד כוכבים ודיני הכנסת שבת](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0071_L2) - :

> וְיֵשׁ לִקְרוֹת כָּל פָּרָשָׁה, דְּהַיְנוּ פְּתוּחָה אוֹ סְתוּמָה, שְׁנֵי פְּעָמִים, וְאַחַר כָּךְ הַתַּרְגּוּם עָלֶיהָ, <sup>(כֵּן הִסְכִּים הַגָּאוֹן הָרַב רַבִּי אֵלִיָהוּ מִוִילְנָא זֵכֶר צַדִּיק לִבְרָכָה)</sup> וַאֲפִלּוּ הַפָּרָשָׁה מְסַיֶּמֶת בְּאֶמְצַע פָּסוּק, יַפְסִיק שָׁם. וּבַגְּמָר יֵשׁ לוֹמַר אַחַר הַתַּרְגּוּם פָּסוּק אֶחָד בַּתּוֹרָה, כְּדֵי לְסַיֵּם בַּתּוֹרָה. וְטוֹב שֶׁלֹּא יַפְסִיק בְּשִׂיחָה בֵּין הַקְּרִיאָה. וְנוֹהֲגִין לִקְרוֹת גַּם הַהַפְטָרָה.‏

- One read each Parsha twice in the original, and then once in the targum
- A Parsha is defined as a Ptucha or Stuma - easily found by the פ or ס the printers put at the end of each Parsha.

  - Even when a Parsha ends in the middle os a verse, one stops there.
- After the last Targum one should read one more verse in the original. (He doesn't say which verse. Maybe the first verse of next week's Parsha. The Be'er Heitev (see  lower down) mentions that the last verse one first says the Targum then the Torah.)
- Best not to interrupt the reading with talking.
- The custom  is to read the Haftara also

The **Be'er Heitev on Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim** 285:1 [סימן רפה - לקרא הפרשה שנים מקרא, ואחד תרגום](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_25.html#HtmpReportNum0043_L2) brings the above method but also mentions an opinion to do one verse at a time; twice Torah, then one Targum.

> באר היטב  (א) תרגום. כתב של''ה שיקרא כל פרשה ב''פ ואח''כ התרגום עליה וכ''כ רש''ל. אבל הל''ח פסק **דיקרא כל פסוק ב' פעמים והתרגום עליו** וכ''כ בהגהות י''נ בשם האר''י וסדה''י וכ''כ בכתבים וכ''כ בספר נגיד ומצוה ובספר משנת חסידים והפסוק האחרון יאמר אחר התרגום כדי לסיים בתורה. ומי שהוא בקי בטעמים ונקודות בע''פ מצוה לקרות בספר תורה מהרדב''ז והאר''י ז''ל תלמיד א' היה לפניו החומש וקרא לפניו. ואיסור גדול להפסיק בקריאת שמו''ת בדיבור. ‏

The Shulchan Aruch ([ibid - 285:2](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_25.html#HtmpReportNum0043_L2)) also brings the option that one can learn Rashi instead of Targum.

> **ב:** אִם לָמַד הַפָּרָשָׁה  בְּפֵרוּשׁ רַשִׁ''י חָשִׁיב כְּמוֹ תַּרְגּוּם, וִירֵא שָׁמַיִם יִקְרָא תַּרְגּוּם וְגַם פֵּרוּשׁ רַשִׁ''י.‏

The Be'er Heitev says that it's better to use a translation, if one can't understand Rashi (nor Targum).

> באר היטב  (ג) פירוש רש''י. היינו מי שיכול להבין אבל מי שאינו בר הכי **ודאי ראוי לקרות בפי' התורה שיש בלשון אשכנז כגון ספר צאינה וראינה וכיוצא בו כדי שיבין ענין הפרשה** ולפי חכמי הקבלה משמע דוקא תרגום. מי שאין בידו תרגום יקרא ב''פ מקרא ואח''כ כשיהיה לו תרגום יקרא סדה''י: ‏

The **Aruch Hashulchan** ([ibid](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01582.html#HtmpReportNum0203_L2)) mentions a third method: Some say to read the entire weekly portion; twice in the original and then in the Targum.

> **ז:** ויש שקורין כל הסדרה, ואחר כך פעם שני, ואחר כך התרגום. וכן משמע קצת מלשון רש''י בברכות שם, ומלשון הגמרא שאומר: ''רב ביבי בר אביי סבר לאשלמינהו לפרשייתא דכולי שתא במעלי יומא דכפורי, וכו''', והכוונה היא לכל הסדרות. ואחר כך אומר: 'סבר לאקדומינהו', ופירש רש''י (דבור המתחיל ''לאקדומינהו''): ''לסדר כל הפרשיות בשבת אחת'', עיין שם, הרי שקרא להסדרה ''פרשה''. ‏

He also mentions (a 4th opinion) that some do a little bit of *Shnayim Mikra V'Echad Targum* every day, and finish it off on Shabbat.

> ויש בני אדם שנוהגים לקרא מעט בכל יום ויום מהשבוע, ומסיימין בשבת (תר''י)‏

He is unsure if changing the order to Torah-Targum-Torah would invalidate the *Shnayim Mikra V'Echad Targum*.

> **ג:** ויש להסתפק: אי בעינן דווקא שנים מקרא מקודם, ואחר כך תרגום, או שיצא כשקרא מקרא ותרגום ומקרא.‏

The **קיצור ש''ע ילקוט יוסף** in 285:3,4 [סימן רפה - לקרוא הפרשה ב' מקרא וא' תרגום](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01355_part_22.html#HtmpReportNum0041_L2) says:

- Even if one doesn't understand it, one must do Targum.
- A Gcd-fearing person should also do Rashi.
- According to the Mekubalim one should do the entire *Shnayim Mikra V'Echad Targum* at a single seating without interruptions.

> ג אף מי שאינו מבין כל כך את שפת התרגום, עליו לקרוא את הפרשה שנים מקרא ואחד תרגום. וירא שמים יקרא גם תרגום וגם פירוש רש''י על הפרשה. [ילקו''י שבת כרך א עמוד שנח].‏
>
> ד על פי דברי המקובלים צריך לקרוא את הפרשה כל פסוק ופסוק שנים מקרא ואחד תרגום, עד סיום כל הפרשה, בהמשך אחד.‏

I'm sure there are other opinions.

Comment: also , is it okay to skip to the Parshas HaShavuah if one is behind . Sources are appreciated .

Comment: @Selef1110 - please ask that as another question.